# Reset rateit stars

Tags: jquery-plugins

I am using jquery.rateit.min.js to performing the rating functionality. I have a cancel button on which i need to reset the selected stars. Below the code snippet :

Cancel

Can anyone let me know how to reset the selected stars.
I used the follwing function to reset but it was not invoking on click of the Cancel button.
$("#rate").bind('reset', function () { $('#rating1').val('0'); });

Thanks & Regards,
Santosh Kumar Patro

Comment: [you can found answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35504140/1915855)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do something like

$("#Q1a_1").bind('reset', function() { $("#hdnID").val(0); });

and reset the value to 0 and store it in hidden field.

Answer (score 5):

<strike>Its not completely clear what your question is.
But you can change the value of the rating by calling:</strike>

```
$('#rate').rateit('value', 0 */new value/*);
```

Since rateit version 1.0.5 the way to reset the rating has been changed to:

```
$('#rate').rateit('value', null); //so set the value to null
```